# Add LinearLayout to ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-view

I have got custom class which is extending `ViewGroup` class. Inside it I want to add some views including two buttoons which has to be next to each other. I came up with idea of creating XML file with this view and then add it using addView. Unfortunately it doesn't work out.

My second idea, which I think is better was creating LineraLayout programmatically along with two buttons, setting up all the settings and then adding.

This is the code:

```
//adding view to view group
addView(createView(ctx));

//function creating linearlayout and buttons
private View createView(Context ctx){
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(ctx);
        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        Button btnL = new Button(ctx);
        btnL.setText("Text1");
        Button btnR = new Button(ctx);
        btnR.setText("Text2");
        l.addView(btnL);
        l.addView(btnR);
        return l;
    }
```

The problem is, that I don't see this view now at all. I mean this created from LinearLayout. There is no error in LogCat.

Can someone please tell me what I have to do to add it?

**EDIT:**

This is code for `onLayout`, I don't have `onMeasure`:

```
@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            int ii = i * 4;
            float fl = w * COORDS[ii] / GRID_WIDTH;
            float ft = h * COORDS[ii + 1] / GRID_HEIGHT;
            float fr = fl + w * COORDS[ii + 2] / GRID_WIDTH;
            float fb = ft + h * COORDS[ii + 3] / GRID_HEIGHT;
            v.layout(Math.round(fl), Math.round(ft), Math.round(fr),
                    Math.round(fb));
        }
    }
```

In general I am just using huge table where I have got info what exact dimensions of given view should be.

Comment: It would help to see the code for the `onMeasure` and `onLayout` methods of your custom `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Why does you first idea with loading two buttons from xml do not work?

Comment: @MateuszZając Just because I've got this same outcome. If you have any working one example I would be glad to see it.

Comment: here you go. example below in answer

Comment: why do ypu want. to add an layout to your ViewGroup?

Comment: @pskink Just because I don't know how other way I can add two buttons using your method in one View cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

override your custom ViewGroup's onMeasure() like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {
        View v = getChildAt(i);
        int ii = i * 4;
        float fw = w * COORDS[ii+2] / GRID_WIDTH;
        float fh = h * COORDS[ii+3] / GRID_HEIGHT;
        int wSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Math.round(fw), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int hSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Math.round(fh), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        Log.d(TAG, "onMeasure Width " + MeasureSpec.toString(wSpec) + ", Height " + MeasureSpec.toString(hSpec));
        v.measure(wSpec, hSpec);
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first idea I am giving you a example from my project as you asked.

It is based on a simple idea. I have an element designed in xml layout file. I load it from xml layout file. I change few things and finally I add it to an element that is currently being viewed on screen.

```
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.android_messenger_sent_message, null);
                TextView inbox_message = (TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.sentMessage);
                inbox_message.setText(conversationInfo.getBody());

                TextView inbox_messageStatus = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.sentMessageStatus);
          String dateStatus = getDateForStatus(conversationInfo.getDateSent());
          inbox_messageStatus.setText(""+dateStatus+" "+getString(R.string.me));

                linearLayoutGlobal.addView(relativeLayout,0);
```

XML layout file from here below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contact_ico" />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/sentMessageStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12:59, FirstName LastName"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sentMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a long sample message and what if it will be toooooooo long?"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show also, how you create `linearLayoutGlobal`, because I think there is an issue that I am fighting with. And second thing - I suppose that your code is inside Activity and as I am using class extending ViewGroup this is useless.